# RSI SMA crossover strategy needs False signal fix

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0

//@version=5
//

strategy('RSI Crossover Strategy', shorttitle='RSI Cross', default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, initial_capital=1000, calc_on_every_tick=true)

// inputs
rsiLength = input(title='RSI Length', defval=50)

smaLength = input(title='SMA Length', defval=25)
// data/series

rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsiLength)

sma = ta.sma(rsi, smaLength)

// plot

plotColor = rsi > sma ? color.green : color.red

rsiPlot = plot(rsi, color=color.new(plotColor, 0), title='RSI')

smaPlot = plot(sma, color=color.new(#cc1111, 0), title='SMA')

fillColor = rsi > sma ? color.lime : color.red

fill(rsiPlot, smaPlot, color=color.new(fillColor, 75))

oversoldLine = hline(30, title='Oversold level')

overboughtLine = hline(70, title='Overbought level')

// strategy

buy = ta.crossover(rsi, sma)

sell = ta.crossunder(rsi, sma)

if buy == true

    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, comment='Buy')

if sell == true

    strategy.close('Long', comment='Sell')
```

Currently when RSI closes 1 candle above MA, indicator understand that as a Bullish signal and then produces Buy Signal on the second candle’s opening. opposite for Sell long signal.

Problem is false signals, because when RSI closes 1st candle above MA and then right when 2nd candle opens Indicator gives Buy signal but the 2nd candle closes Below SMA giving false buy signal and then sell signal later if 3rd candle closes below MA as well.

I would greatly appreciate if you can help adding little code where indicator only produces buy signal if 1st and 2nd candle close above MA and Sell long signal when 1st and 2nd candle closes below MA.

Comment: i actually use daily candle instead of hourly. just mentioned hourly to simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

For a second candle confirmation, it is just an addition of the following code in your entry and exit logic:

```
if buy[1] and rsi > sma

    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, comment='Buy')

if sell[1] and rsi < sma

    strategy.close('Long', comment='Sell')
```

This checks that the previous candle was a cross and that the current candle still follows in the same direction.

---

Edit in response to the first comment:

In my testing, it is doing exactly as you asked. FInd the screenshot below:
[image]

At the white arrow marked candle (both buy and sell), the cross occurred. At the yellow arrow marked candle, the follow-up condition (rsi > ema / rsi < ema) is satisfied. At the blue arrow marked candle open, the trade is taken/closed. If you want to enter/exit on the second candle close, add `process_orders_on_close=true` in your `strategy()` function.

Comment: hi rakesh, if the second candle closes successfully above MA only then Buy signal should appear and sell long signal should come only if 1st as well as 2nd candle close below MA. (so my entry should be at the close of second candle or opening of 3rd candle). with your code - Buy signal is appearing on the third candle regardless of 2nd candle closes above or not.

Comment: Please find the edit in the answer above.

Comment: thanks Rakesh so much! it was my mistake, its working how i want. thanks again for your time.